# In Meteor How to find a DOM element (after render)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm new to meteor.

I want to use JavaScript to copy text from an h1-element into a div-element.

I started with this:

```
cd /tmp
meteor create dad
cd dad
meteor deploy dad.meteor.com
```

I created a template:

```
<template name='dad1'>
  <h1 id='id1'>hello</h1>
  <h2 id='id2'>world</h2>
</template>
```

I wroted some js:

```
// dad1.js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.dad1.onRendered(function(){
    var myh1 = this.find('id1');
    var myh2 = this.find('id2');})}
```

When I step through the above js in my browser both myh1 and myh2 stay null.

Question:
How to find a DOM element (after render) so I can operate on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [template's `find` method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_find) takes a CSS selector as the argument, so you'd need to pass `#id1` instead of `id1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myh1 = document.getElementById('id1');
```

or with jQuery

```
var myh1 = $('#id1')
```